# LazyInitializationException with simple domain model (Spring Boot/JPA)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am building an application with a simple domain model. The project uses Spring Boot and JPA. Some of the model is as follows:

AbstractEntity.java:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;
  ...
}
```

Task.java:

```
@Entity
public class Task extends AbstractEntity {
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
  private List<TaskNote>           notes        = new ArrayList<>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
  private List<StateChangeHistory> stateHistory = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
}
```

TaskNote.java:

```
@Entity
public class TaskNote extends AbstractEntity {
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  private Task   task;
  ...
}
```

StateChangeHistory.java:

```
@Entity
public class StateChangeHistory extends AbstractEntity {
  @ManyToOne
  private Task           task;
  ...
}
```

MainView.java (I am using Vaadin):

```
@Route("")
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
  private Grid<Task>  grid = new Grid<>(Task.class);
  private TaskService taskService;

  public MainView(TaskService taskService) {
    this.taskService = taskService;
    ...
    updateGrid();
  }
  ...
  private void updateGrid() {
    grid.setItems(taskService.findAll());
  }
}
```

I am building the main view, which currently just has a list of `Task`s. The view uses a `@Service` to take care of retrieving and saving data via a `JpaRepository` implementation.

TaskRepository.java:

```
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {
}
```

There are similar repository classes for other class fields (e.g. `TaskNote`).

TaskService.java:

```
@Service
public class TaskService {
  private TaskRepository      taskRepository;

  public TaskService(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
    this.taskRepository = taskRepository;
  }
  ...
  // Load some test data.
  @PostConstruct
  public void populateTestData() {
    if (taskRepository.count() == 0) {
      Task task = null;
      TaskNote note = null;

      task = new Task("Task-1");
      note = new TaskNote();
      note.setNote("note");
      task.getNotes().add(note);

      taskRepository.save(task);
      taskRepository.save(new Task("TEST-2"));
    }
  }
}
```

I am encountering a `LazyInitializationException`, which is apparently a pretty common occurrence - at least to us JPA/Hibernate noobs.

The exception is like the following:

```
[DEBUG] 2020-11-20 14:50:52.801 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DispatcherServlet - Failed to complete request: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mycompany.tasks.backend.entity.Task.notes, could not initialize proxy - no Session
[ERROR] 2020-11-20 14:50:52.803 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mycompany.tasks.backend.entity.Task.notes, could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mycompany.tasks.backend.entity.Task.notes, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I started Googling and found an interesting article that discusses correct ways to deal with this problem, as well as "solutions" that **should not** be used.

Here is the link:
https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/#How_to_fix_the_LazyInitializationException

I don't really understand what is presented in the article. I know very little about data persistence in Java. I've been under the impression that the usage of Spring, etc. helped to make doing this work much simpler than how it was done in the past.

The gist I'm getting from what I'm seeing and have read is that I need to get the subordinate (e.g. the notes for a task) data when I get the "parent". I guess that makes sense, but I don't know how to go about it. The examples provided in the article seems to require writing code that requires fairly good knowledge of Hibernate or JPA. It also seems to go against the grain of the "simplicity" that Spring, etc. is aiming to provide. Perhaps it's not that complicated, but I don't know enough to be able to judge that.

I'm looking for understanding and ways to find a solution to make this work.

**UPDATE 1 - 11/24/2020**

I decided to try using the `@NamedEntityGraph` annotation to see if this could help. However, I suspect that for this to truly work, I need to use it with an `EntityManager` instance. I'm not sure *where* I should use the entity manager - in the `@Service` or in the `TaskRepository`. I also need to do some more research to understand how to use it. Any suggestions in this area would be helpful.

This is just my impression, but it seems that this adds complexity to the code to set up specialized query logic in order to get a `Task` and all of its associated sub-objects in one go. And this is all so as to avoid the `LazyInitializationException`. Doesn't Spring and/or JPA/Hibernate handle this without the extra customization?

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 2 - 11/24/2020**

I have modified code as follows:

Task.java:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.task", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("notes"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("stateHistory") })
public class Task extends AbstractEntity {
...
}
```

TaskRepository.java:

```
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long>, TaskRepositoryCustom {
}
```

TaskRepositoryCustom.java:

```
public interface TaskRepositoryCustom {
  List<Task> findAll();
}
```

TaskRepositoryCustomImpl.java:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class TaskRepositoryCustomImpl implements TaskRepositoryCustom {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public List<Task> findAll() {
    EntityGraph<?> graph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("graph.task");

    TypedQuery<Task> query = entityManager.createQuery("select t from Task t", Task.class)
        .setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);

    return query.getResultList();
  }

}
```

This appears to have resolved the `LazyInitializationException` problem, but has produced a new one:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.mycompany.tasks.ui.MainView': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mycompany.tasks.ui.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [com.mycompany.tasks.backend.entity.Task.stateHistory, com.mycompany.tasks.backend.entity.Task.notes]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [com.mycompany.tasks.backend.entity.Task.stateHistory, com.mycompany.tasks.backend.entity.Task.notes]
```

Comment: Where is the error being thrown from? Is it from the `PostConstruct` block? I feel we're missing some code here.

Comment: Have you tried the annotation `@Transactional` ? 
What I normally do after having created the repositories, is to create services responsible for the queries, and then tag those services with transactional... 

In your case, you could try to annotate `TaskService` with `@Transactional` and see if it works

Comment: I tried `@Transactional` on the `@Service`, but that didn't help.

Comment: I have updated the code listings to provide more detail. I have also removed the `@NamedEntityGraph` stuff for now.

Comment: Override findAll in TaskRepository

e.g.

    @EntityGraph(value = "taskGraph",type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    public List<Task> findAll()..

Comment: Hmm, OK. What do I need to do in the overridden `findAll()`?